# what are these brown buds on rose plant stem

Tags: identification, plant-care, roses, bugs, stems

I often see these brown buds on my rose plant stems, What are these Brow buds, are these harmful? if so how to prevent/cure these.

[image]

They can be removed easily, but rose Thorns make it difficult.
(front)
[image]

(back)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They look rather like a form of scale insect - rose scale usually looks white, but living where you do, it's possible other forms  of scale are more common. Those flattish brown objects can be removed by using 70% alcohol or methylated spirits and a rag - just moisten a rag lightly and rub it over the firm, thick stems to get them off, but keep it off any soft growth. There will likely also be nymphs, which don't look the same and are quite difficult to see, so after you've removed the brown deposits, spray the whole plant, especially soft green growth (leaves, backs of leaves, stems) with neem oil spray or a horticultural oil spray.

Comment: Scraping scale off with a finger nail is effective depending on the size of the plant .

Comment: Thanks for response, I live in South India if it matters.
Not sure where can I get 70% alcohol or methylated spirits, can I use surgical spirit instead? And use ear buds? Plant is small in a 16" pot.

Comment: surgical spirit will do, but you might find you can just use a damp cloth and rub quite hard, just moistened with water, give it a try,it might work.